# Why Web to PDF conversion isn't working in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I wanted to save some specific web pages as PDF using chrome browser(current version). So I added extensions one by one like 'Save as PDF','Web2PDFConverter' and 'HTML To PDF Converter'. But they saved,

- my gmail account page as GMail Login Page.
- Google search results page as Just empty google search page.

Why they do like this? Any other extension available to save my exact web page as PDF?

And one more question is, why they ask,
"This type of file can harm your computer. Do you want to keep *.pdf anyway? - (KEEP DISCARD as buttons)" after the conversion, just to save a PDF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to convert **without adding extensions** to chrome.

Simply click the wrench icon in the top right corner.

**Print** -> Set Destination as **Save as PDF** -> **Save** -> **give the location & name** for the PDF.

This gives my gmail account page and google search result page as I want.